# Iterating array in arm assembler for Android

Tags: android, assembly, java-native-interface, arm

I want to iterate array array in arm assembly for Android but I'm getting FATAL SIGNAL error and app crash.

I will show what is inside.

First of all I'm using jni to access c code from java:

I declared native function:

```
public native byte[] BitmapToGrayscale(byte[] bitmap);
```

After that I call my code by calling this function:

```
 private void ConvertImageToGrayscale()
{
    if(image == null)
    {
        GetLenaBack();
        info("Nie było obrazu, ustawiono domyślny.");
    }

    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(image.getByteCount());
    image.copyPixelsToBuffer(bb);
    info("Start");
    ByteBuffer result = ByteBuffer.wrap(this.BitmapToGrayscale(bb.array()));
    info("Stop");
    image.copyPixelsFromBuffer(result);
    display.setImageBitmap(image);
}
```

Function in C looks like:

```
JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_pl_marekbar_Main_BitmapToGrayscale
(JNIEnv * env, jobject thisObj, jbyteArray bitmap)
{
    jbyte arraySize = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, bitmap);
    jbyte *arrayAddress = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, bitmap, 0);
    jbyte cellSize = sizeof((*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, bitmap, 0));

    Grayscale(arrayAddress, arraySize, cellSize);
    return bitmap;
}
```

And finally this is my asm code:

```
@ This file is jni/Grayscale.s
    .text
    .align  2
    .global Grayscale
    .type   Grayscale, %function
Grayscale:
@Convert to grayscale
    stmfd   sp!, {fp,ip,lr}
@r0 - pointer
@r1 - array length
@r2 - array element size
    mov r3, #0 @current element
array_loop:
    ldr r4, [r0] @load element to memory


    str r4, [r0] @store element in memory
    add r0, r0, r4 @move pointer
    add r3, r3, #1 @increment index

    cmp r3, r1 @compare current index with array length
    bne array_loop @when index smaller than array length still iterate


    ldmfd   sp!, {fp,ip,lr}
    bx  lr
    .size   Grayscale, .-Grayscale
```

I need to find out how to properly work with arrays passed from c code in arm asm. I don't want to do this in C because I'm preparing app for image processing and must be quick.

Comment: You're moving the pointer in a rather odd fashion (increasing it by the 32-bit value you just loaded from the array). Are you sure that's correct?

Comment: Without looking into it very deeply, your assembly-code uses r4 without saving it to the stack. Only r0-r3, ip and lr can be modified without saving them. Just use r3 instead of r4 and decrement r1 till it hits 0 to loop over your array. This should at least stop it from crashing. But the code on it self does not look very efficient after all. And as Michael pointed out, you probably wanted to increment r0 by r2 and not r4.

Comment: Also, what's `cellSize` supposed to be? The number of bytes per pixel? By the looks of it you're setting it to the size of a pointer, which will be at least 4 bytes.

Comment: I think that pixel consists of 4 bytes - ARGB pixel - png image. I want to get whole pixel to register and than manipulate.

Comment: You shouldn't bother with ARM assembly for image processing. You definitely should go for NEON since it's extremely fast for this kind of jobs and much easier to program than ARM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your combination of `arraySize` and `cellSize` looks incorrect:

```
jbyte arraySize = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, bitmap);
jbyte cellSize = sizeof((*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, bitmap, 0));
```

1. A `jbyte` is an `int8_t` (i.e. a signed 8-bit type). Therefore `arraySize` likely won't be able to hold the actual length of the array, unless your image is very small.
2. You´re setting `cellSize` to the size of a `jbyte*`, which most likely will be 4 bytes. This just so happens to correspond to the size of a 32-bit ARGB pixel, but it's still not a correct way of determining the size of each pixel. That information should be passed from the Java code to the C code as another argument.
3. Since your assembly code iterates `arraySize` times, it will attempt to read `arraySize` words (i.e. `arraySize * 4` bytes). But your array only contains `arraySize` *bytes*.

---

You're using the wrong increment for the array pointer in your assembly code:

```
ldr r4, [r0] @load element to memory
add r0, r0, r4 @move pointer
```

What you're adding to the pointer is the pixel data you just read from the array. Like @Masta79 commented, what you probably wanted was to add `r2` (the element size) to the pointer.

Comment: I did as you said. I passed array length and pixel size from java to C and then to asm. I can now read pixel into register and clear it with zero and then save. I'm not sure how I should split pixel into parts from register. ldr command load 32 bits into register - the whole pixel. I think that I must use some mask, am I right?

Comment: To convert ARGB to grayscale I'd use something like `((R*0.299 + G*0.587 + B*0.114) * A) / 256`